# how to do 'ls -lrt' of data from a input file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have an input file `file.csv` (data separated by comma delimiter) which will have only 3 comma-delimited rows. The data will be file names.

E.g:

```
test,test1,test2,test3,,n
a,b,c,d,,n
p,q,r,s,,n
```

Now, I have a requirement that the first row of file `file.csv` data exist or not in directory `abc` with command `ls -lrt`. The output of this command should be redirected to a text file `a.txt`.

E.g:

```
ls -lrt test
ls -lrt test1
....
```

Next: Second row of the `file.csv` data  in directory `abc` with command `ls -lrt`. The output of this command should be appended to a text file `a.txt`.

E.g:

```
ls -lrt a
ls -lrt b
....
```

Next: Third row of the `file.csv` data  in directory `xyz` with command `ls -lrt`. The output of this command should be appended to a text file `a.txt`.

E.g:

```
ls -lrt p
ls -lrt q
....
```

Sample output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 dba  dba  122 Jan 21 06:44 test
ls: p: No such file or directory
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Actually I don't no how to read a input file data for ls -lrt command .because I will have test,test,1,test2,...n in 1 row.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and perhaps reformat your question accordingly. As it is, your question is probably both unclear and too broad.

Comment: Input file format is .csv  an Yes , In each row each column contains number of ls -lrt out put lines. And I need to see datetime/user/file_permissions as well. i.e ROW 1= test,test1,test3 then ls -lrt test /ls -lrt test1 /ls -lrt test 3 like wise.

Comment: Those do not look like `ls -l` output lines.  `test` would look something like `-rw-rw-rw- user 123 Feb 2 test` in `ls -l` output.  If the row just contains a comma-separated list of file names to examine, that makes things somewhat easier; but until you clarify, your question is still unclear.

Comment: What's the significance of the empty fields in the input file?

Comment: it is not empty ...I meant it till n columns.(E.G: ......n)

Comment: @teepu I hope you're not planning to [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
dirs=(abc abc xyz)
index=1
while read -r line; do
    IFS=,
    for f in $line; do
        ls -lrt "${dirs[$index]}/$f" 2>&1
    done
    let index++
done <file.csv >a.txt
```

Keeping an array of directories to examine for each iteration isn't particularly elegant; perhaps you could massage your input data or problem statement into something internally consistent.

Arrays are a Bash feature, so will not work with `sh` (but are supported in similar form in `ksh` and `zsh` as well, I believe).

This would be somewhat more elegant if you didn't use comma-separated input.  The shell is excellent at parsing space-separated tokens.  We muck with `IFS=,` to achieve much the same effect for a comma-separated list of values to drive the `for` loop.

Comment: I want the code to read 1st line nd chk....then one more block t chk next line...how can I do this

Comment: I don't understand. Is this code not doing what you asked for?

Comment: I am using the below code to read and process first line                                                                                                            `cd $abc                                                                                                     while read -r line; do
    IFS=,
    for f in $line; do
        echo `ls -lrt $f 2>>a.txt` >> a.txt
    done
done <file.csv `  When i am trying to read second line i am getting error as File `file.csv` does not exist . How will I close the file before reading 2nd line????

Comment: There should be no need for that, though the other changes you have made might be detrimental. The [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) should not cause this, but is certainly a bad idea. The double redirection inside the loop looks like a syntax error to me, but might be the culprit here; my code does the redirection outside the loop quite on purpose, as it simplifies the code, and is also more efficient.